# Disable Entity Framework 4.1 Optimistic Concurrency Checking on all Entities

Tags: entity-framework-4

I used the model first approach using DBContext to create EF 4.1 Data Model.  I would like to turn off Optimistic Concurrency Checking on my entire database because I do not need it.

What is the easiest way to do this?  I would prefer to do this through the designer, but if not possible, maybe there is an DBContext/ObjectContext way to do this?

Please help thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no optimistic concurrency by default. If you want to use the concurrency checking you must configure it in your model - each property has `Concurrency Mode` configuration which defaults to `None`. Unless you change it to `Fixed` value optimistic concurrency is not used. There is also no global configuration to turn concurrency checking on or off.

Comment: Hmmm that can't be right because I am getting OptimisticConcurrencyExceptions in certain cases and i've verified that the Concurrency Mode is set to None.  Any other ideas?

Comment: You must identify why are you getting the exception. What operations did you execute? This for example happens if you try to modify entity which was already deleted. In such case you must handle the error - there is no way to avoid it.

Comment: So im still confused, if optimistic concurrency checking is not on by default, why would Optimistic Concurrency Exceptions be thrown in the first place?  I checked my entire .edmx file to ensure that there were not any properties set to Concurrency Mode=fixed

Comment: EF still check the row_count to validate that the right number of rows were affected by changes. It assumes the only way to get an incorrect row count is for a concurrency issue to have been raised. But that is incorrect if you have triggers that could affect the row count on the database.

Comment: Row count is not affected by triggers.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be correct. I just came across this answer when Googling how to switch this option off. In my case I hit the issue when inserting into a table with `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON`. This setting is intentional. I just want to fire the inserts and ignore duplicate key values. The mismatch between rows inserted and sent causes an unwanted `OptimisticConcurrencyException` with the transaction rolled back.